# Install and Run Oracle SQL on a MAC

Tags: sql, oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm driving a little crazy... I need to install and run the "HR" database on SQL Developer on my Mac. I've dowloaded the SQL developer... but now I don't know how to make the connection... 
I'm pretty new in this, so any help will be awesome.

Comment: What version of Oracle Database are you targeting? Have you seen these documents? https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/macos/documentation/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There's no Oracle database available for MAC. And SQL Developer is just a client - it lets you work with a database, but it IS NOT A DATABASE.

[I talk about what your options are here in depth](https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303) but the easiest way to go is to pull down our [VirtualBox image](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html) and run that - it's all free for learning purposes.

[image]

HR is on there, you can logon as HR/oracle@localhost:1521/orcl

Answer (score 0):

Get Oracle Virtual Box and install the virtual appliance, also available on OTN. Both are free, assuming you're not trying to run a production instance.